# Excel Worksheet_Change Event not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro where changing any column 
should automatically save worksheet.

My Excel sheet expands till `G25`.

I tried this but its not working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("G25")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I have save it under `ThisWorkBook`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under **ThisWorkbook** that handler is called `Workbook_SheetChange` and it accepts two arguments, **Sh** (of type `Object`) and **Target** (a `Range`). So, your code won't work there.
If you put your code in the sheet you want (**Sheet1**, for instance) instead of in the **ThisWorkbook**, put the `End If` and change the range to **"A1:G25"** (representing a square from row 1 column A to row 25 column 25), it should work.
This did:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:G25")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

For completeness, under **ThisWorkbook**, this will work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:G25")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: or a little more succinctly `Intersect(Target, Sh.[A1:G25])`

Answer (score 11):

The other common reason why an Event doesn't work is that EnableEvents has been set to False

I would code your problem like this as

- typically you need to work with the range of interest that is being tested. So creating a variable `rng1` below serves both as an early exit point, and a range object to work with. On a sheet event `Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:G25")` will work but it is lengthy for it's actual use
- If you do have a range to manipulate then making any further changes to the sheet will trigger a recalling of the Change event and so on, which can cause Excel to crash. So it is best to disable further Events, run your code, then re-enable Events on exit

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:G25"))
  If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  'work with rng1
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  End Sub
  ```