# Auto Resize Row Height after pasting in Excel

Tags: excel, row, vba

I use MS Excel 2007 to make Bills and Quotation. Often I need to reuse previous quotation.

After I copy  a quotation and paste it to new location the row height needs to be readjusted for each row.

is there any solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I suggest that `.EntireRow.AutoFit` might be your first point of call.

Comment: Maybe use the Paste Special dialog to paste formulae and values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you are after. But have you tried something like this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   ' Here you enter a matrix with the cells you want to trigger a Autofit
   ' If you just want one column to do it, take Range("A1:A200") 
    Range("A1:C11").EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

This code gets the row-size auto-fitted everytime you change the value in the choosen cells.

It's hard to come up with a good solution when you do not give to much information.

Check here :
[Excel Worksheet_Change Event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071931/excel-worksheet-change-event-not-working) if my code didn't help you.

Best Regards