# Worksheet_Change event not working in older Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a macro that updates the values on the axis of a chart.

It's assigned to each sheet individually rather than to the whole workbook so I'm pretty sure this fix:
'[Excel Worksheet_Change Event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071931/excel-worksheet-change-event-not-working)'
doesn't apply.

It's working fine for me on Excel 2013 but when I send it to other users with Excel 2003 & 2007 it doesn't work.

I've tried adding application.event enabling/disabling in case that was what was stopping it - didn't work.

Also tried looking for a library tick box but nothing jumped out.

Here's the code as is:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Format graph axis depending on what the dropdown value is

Dim DropBox As Range
Dim PaxRange As Range
Dim RevRange As Range
Dim AveRange As Range
Dim YoyRange As Range

Set DropBox = Range("FC96")
Set PaxRange = Range("A97")
Set RevRange = Range("A98")
Set AveRange = Range("A99")
Set YoyRange = Range("A100")

     If Not Intersect(Target, DropBox) Is Nothing Then
            If DropBox.Value = PaxRange.Value Then
                'If it's passengers
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
                ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
                Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
            End If

            If DropBox.Value = RevRange.Value Then
                'If it's revenue
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
                ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
                Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "£#,##0"
            End If

            If DropBox.Value = AveRange.Value Then
                'If it's average
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
                ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
                Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00"
            End If

            If DropBox.Value = YoyRange.Value Then
                'If it's year-on-year
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
                ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
                Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0%"
            End If
            DropBox.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Pretty new to VBA, couldn't find anyone who'd had the same problem.
Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Good practice is always narrowing the generic statement _it doesn't work_ to the questions: 1) does it fail on a specific code line (--> if yes, which line) or the event is not fired at all? 2) If it's a fail, what is the error message you get?

Comment: *I'm pretty sure this fix [...] doesn't apply* - but did you try it?

Comment: @drfosterrainsnafu: What error message are you getting? Also, if you disable events then nothing will happen at all ...

Comment: Is `TickLabels` available in Excel 2003/2007 - I thought it was introduced to the Object Model as an enhancement with Excel 2010!

Comment: Mat - I did try the fix above, yes.
There's no error message coming up to debug, that's the confusing thing - otherwise I'd go through the process of looking up the error message etc..

As I say, it's working fine on my machine, formatting the axis exactly as I wanted it to but then when I send it to other people the code doesn't seem to run at all.

I've checked the 'view code' option on the sheet tab and the code's there, just not running.

Thanks again all.

Comment: Also, by tick box I meant going through the menu in the VBA environment (tools > references) to tick/untick the libraries the sheet calls.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out in the end so for the benefit of anyone else who's as bad at vba as I am:

The issue was that people I was sending it to had macro security setting that weren't allowing the macro to run.

The solutions as simple as asking them to change their macro security settings which you do like  [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-macro-security-settings-in-Excel-a97c09d2-c082-46b8-b19f-e8621e8fe373)  (Microsoft Office Support).

Thanks.