# vba excel Worksheet_Change input info have vba find row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell I would like to be able to type a number let say 010 into cell E3 and have VBA after I'm done do a search into a different worksheet where it well do a find and give me the row number (variable). But I can't figure out how to tell VBA to do its search after I'm done (click enter?)

I'm bad with Worksheet_Change too. For the most part this is the code that works but I don't know how to set up worksheet_change and how to get it to work when I'm done typing.

```
 Sub tester()
    Dim MyRange As Range

   Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("E2")
   With ActiveSheet
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
    Test = Range("E2").Value
    Sheets("CC").Select
        Columns("A:A").Select
    Set test2 = Selection.Find(What:=Test, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
MsgBox (test2)
    End If
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Here is a good reference to using Worksheet_Change.  The `If Not Intersect(Target, Range_Of_Interest) Is Nothing Then ... End If` pattern is typical for trapping changes to a given area.  Try creating something like that and update your question with what you tried. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071931/excel-worksheet-change-event-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
   If Target = [E2] Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("E2")) Then
            On Error GoTo Errhandler

            RRvalue = Sheets("RR").Range("E2").Value
            Sheets("CC").Select
            Columns("A:A").Select
            Selection.Find(What:=RRvalue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

            Row = ActiveCell.Row

            Sheets("CC").Range("A" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("E2").MergeArea
            Sheets("CC").Range("B" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("B1").MergeArea
            Sheets("CC").Range("C" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("H4").MergeArea
            Sheets("CC").Range("D" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("H5").MergeArea
            Sheets("CC").Range("E" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("H6").MergeArea
            Sheets("CC").Range("F" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("H7").MergeArea
            Sheets("CC").Range("G" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("H8").MergeArea
            Sheets("CC").Range("H" & Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("RR").Range("I1").MergeArea
            Sheets("RR").Select

            Exit Sub
Errhandler:
            Sheets("RR").Select
            MsgBox "Didn't find the number " & RRvalue

        End If
End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This was the code i was looking for look like i didnt need any added code to check when the text was enter as it already does that :D

```
 If Target = [E2] Then
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("E2")) Then
```