# xlwings error when triggered by Worksheet_Calculate when calculation on automatic

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a function call:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Debug.Print Now()

    If check_data_required_is_present Then
        Call d2s_caller
    Else

    End If


End Sub
```

Where d2s_caller is:

```
Sub d2s_caller()
Application.StatusBar = "Strike conversion"
    RunPython ("import f_v; f_v.calc_s_callback()")
Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

When I delete an array for the calculation to trigger, I (more often than not) get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------

Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this? Is this a non-threadsafe aspect of xlwings that is being exposed?

Is xlwings being called multiple times by excel?

If I am in manual calculation the issue goes away, but under automatic it persists.

Answer (score 2):

By all means I'm no XlWings or even python expert but I've reproduced your error. I took the Fibonacci Sequence example from the xlwings page.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = 1 Then
        Debug.Print Now()
        RunFrozenPython ("fibonacci.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```

First testing the trigger with a simple calculation to see that is works.
In one cell:

```
    =1+1
```

This works just as expected. It triggers the python code and everything is executed without errors.
If we stress excel a bit and ask the python code to calculate 100 Fibonacci numbers and the sum them up it will produce the same error as you.

```
=SUM(C:C)
```

My guess is that Excel is indeed calling multiple times. Probably there is some issue to call xlwings before the first call is done.

You could try to use Worksheet_Change instead and only use one cell to minimize the python calls.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print Now()
        RunFrozenPython ("fibonacci.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```

[Excel Worksheet_Change Event - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071931/excel-worksheet-change-event-not-working)

Comment: Indeed I will give it a try. Thanks Daniel.