# DateDiff Contingent Upon Cell Change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have excel calculate the number of days present when given two date ranges.  The macro works on its own, but I'm having trouble getting the macro to run when the cells that contain the dates are changed.  This is the code that I currently have:

```
Public sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address="$C$32" Then Sheet1.pdates
    End If
End Sub

Public sub pdates()
    Dim pdates as Integer
    Dim pdates2 as Integer
        pdates=DateDiff("d",[D32],[F32])
        pdates2=DateDiff("d",[H32],[J32])
        [L32]=pdates+pdates2
End Sub
```

When I push run, it asks if I want to run Sheet1.pstubs, but doesn't allow the option of running the Worksheet_Change code.  I think I might by using the (ByVal Target as Range) incorrectly.  Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: Which cells contain dates? And how are those dates changed? Manually? Or do the cells have formulas? And is `pdates` Sub written in `Sheet1` module? It also seems a formula in the spreadsheet could work instead of VBA code.

Comment: They are both written in Sheet 1 and the dates would be changed in the sheet manually.  The code for pdates works when I run it, but I can't get it to run when the date in cell C32  changes.

Comment: `but I can't get it to run when the date in cell C32 change` -> what happens? Did you debug, line by line to see why it's not running?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, I'm just not getting a product when it runs.  When I push run, it prompts me to select which macro I want to run, and the only one available is sheets1.pdates.  It's almost as if I'm not able to run the ByVal script.  I'm new to VBA and it seems like this might be a simple conceptual error that I'm missing.

Comment: Did you add the code on the [desired Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8072274/7690982)? Or are you using it on Modules?

Comment: You can not manually run event code. It only triggers when the event occurs. In your case when a cell is changed on the worksheet. Make sure the code itself is written *inside the worksheet module*, not in a standard module. Well, at the `Worksheet_Change` event code. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) for more information. If you keep `pdates` in a module (outside worksheet code) make sure to explicitly state which worksheet object you use.

Comment: Running the code while the cursor is in the `Worksheet_Change` proceduire will cause the outcome you describe. This is normal. Change your If statement to `Stop` or pop up a `MsgBox` when the address is C32. Does it stop or pop up the message?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, all.  All of this context is helping me learn VBA more quickly.   I made a small change in the code and it worked.  I updated my answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but the following changed enabled it to work:

Original:

```
If Target.Address="$C$32" then Sheet1.pdates
End if
```

Change:

```
If Target.Address="$C$32" then
Sheet1.pdates
End if
```

Comment: When you use `If conditional Then Action` on the same line, you don't use `End if`. So if there is `End If`, the actions must be on a newline

Comment: @danieltakeshi - I know. I can't believe I looked right past that! Funny thing is my eyes saw it and thought it looked funny, but I didn't even think too much after that.

Comment: Oh, that totally makes sense! Thanks @danieltakeshi and Scot Holtzman.